# Entity Framework Core how to list one to many from many to many from a model without using Include().ThenInclude()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, entity-framework-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core API with entity framework core and mySQL and i have an issue with listing data from Many to Many tables using ThenInclude(). The data send in JSON keeps referencing relations over relations until it sends over 50kb of data.

[image]

i tried other methods like select:

```
        var orders = await context.orders.Select(o => new Order
        {
            id = o.id,
            OrderProducts = o.OrderProducts.AsQueryable().Include(x => x.product).ToList(),
            ReceiptOrders = o.ReceiptOrders.AsQueryable().Include(x => x.receipt).ToList(),
        }).ToListAsync();
```

but this keeps returning NULL for the product and the receipt in the Many to Many tables. Does anyone have a efficient solution that does give me the relations i requested but not any relations after that.

Comment: `Include` has *nothing* to do with JSON. It only affect eager vs lazy loading. If you want your JSON to have a different shape from your entities, use a `Select` call that returns the shape you want

Comment: BTW you didn't post the actual query, the entities or what you want the results to look like. JSON.NET would complain if they detected a circular reference, and yet that seems to be the problem here. This means that *something* was done to bypass those warnings.

Comment: Did you use `ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` perhaps, to ignore JSON.NET's warning? Which ASP.NET Core/EF Core versions are you using? How was JSON.NET configured?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I ment to say that the data returned keeps including relations with relations. I tried using Select as stated in my question but i doesnt give me the data i request. i want to have the Many to Many tables contain the one to one or many relations. like Example: "OrderProducts = o.OrderProducts.AsQueryable().Include(x => x.product).ToList()" inside the Select function i want to have the Many to Many table OrderProducts to also contain the One to Many back to Product

Comment: That's what `circular reference` means. It's not `Include`'s problem, it's a relations problem and JSON.NET configuration problem. You don't need to put *anything* inside `Select`. The *entire* query is converted to a SQL query and executed. What `Include` does is tell EF Core to generate a JOIN to eagerly load possibly missing data, instead of lazily loading it later. It *doesn't* affect the relations themselves.

Comment: There are many duplicates asking about circular references anyway. In this particular case, if you *don't* want that circular reference, you need to return DTOs that *don't* have it to begin with. You haven't posted *any* code though, so it's impossible to give better advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be explicit!

Sounds strange but you should not feed a serializer an EF entity. It might try to serialize your entire database. Define a object (structure) and fill that with the desired data. We'd like to call those DTOs (Data Transfer Objects).

More info:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649585(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
- http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html
- https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response but you're right. After working more and more with EF Core i now use DTO's for everything that is send to the client or given to the API

Answer (score 0):

use stored procedure to get the exact result

context.Database.SqlQuery("Call Stored Procedure").ToList();